# Why does the Moving Average indicator change values depending on the size of my view?

Tags: yahoo-finance, indicators

I added a 200 period moving average indicator to a Yahoo Finance graph. I assume that "period" denotes 1 day, but I am seeing unexpected behavior.

In the [1 day view](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/QQQ#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%3D) the latest value of the moving average is one value (220 at the moment).
In the [1 year view](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/QQQ#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%3D),  the latest value is different (201 at the moment).

Shouldn't the moving average indicator plot the same values regardless of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible reasons for what cause differences in the data.

A 200 period moving average means 200 periods not 200 days.  If the data used is one minute data then the moving average would be computed on 200 one minute bars.

In order for the latest values to agree on two different charts:

- The time period of the data  must be the same.  Both must be one minute bars or one day bars, etc.
- The starting pointing for the calculation of each MA must be the same even though you are not displaying the full amount of the data in the chart.
- The moving average must be the same type in each calculation (simple, weighted or exponential).

Longer term MAs lag shorter term MAs because longer time period MAs are slower.  IOW, a 200 period EMA on one minute bars will be more responsive than a 200 period EMA on  daily bars.  I suspect that is what is happening here because you have a value of 201 on the 1 year view and a value of 220 on the one day view.

Comment: Got it. It looks like I need to select a chart "Interval" of 1D to get the expected value. Thank you!